# How to create a React-Native framework using Swift

Tags: swift, react-native

I have a react native component written in Swift, and I want to extract it as a framework so other project/people can use it easily.

First I created a new iOS project `Foo`, added a framework target,
then added source files. Finally, I built it.

It failed because:

> Bar.swift:[lineNumber]: Use of unresolved identifier 'RCTConvert'
>       RNBarManager.swift:[lineNUmber]: Use of undeclared type 'RCTViewManager'

#### Attempt 1:

I ran `react-native link`, but nothing changed.

#### Attempt 2:

1. Drag `React.xcodeproj` to `Foo` project and add `libReact.a` to `Link
   Binary With Libraries`.
2. Add `$(SRCROOT)/../node_modules/react-native/React` to `Header Search Paths`.

But it doesn't work. The error still remains.

#### Attempt 3:

I was thinking maybe Swift doesn't recognize these files.

So I added `Foo-Bridging-Headers.h` like I did in a React-Native App, which contains the following code:

```
#import "React/RCTBridge.h"
#import "React/RCTViewManager.h"
#import "React/RCTUIManager.h"
#import "React/UIView+React.h"
#import "React/RCTBridgeModule.h"
```

I also added `Foo-Bridging-Headers.h` to `Build Settings->Swift Compiler - General->Object-C Bridging Header`,

Still I got an error.

> using bridging headers with framework targets is unsupported

It seems bridging headers are not allowed here.

#### Attempt 4:

I tried to add these imports to `Foo.h`,

but got an error again.

> Foo.h:21:9: Include of non-modular header inside framework module 'Foo'

## What should I do to compile successfully?

Comment: maybe you could post this question to [CocoaPods github issue section](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues), I think they will be glad to help you :)

Comment: @XuDong Did you get a solution?

Comment: It seems David Chavez has provided a proper way to ship React Native Charts Wrapper: https://github.com/wuxudong/react-native-charts-wrapper/pull/257

Comment: For creating such framework you can use my https://github.com/iyegoroff/make-react-native-package CLI tool. It creates a publishable RN package with Swift support.

Answer (score 2):

This seems like an issue with the cocoa pods required for linking React to your project.

Try running `pod install` in your project directory using terminal and then try to build.

Answer (score 0):

The linking happens in the hosting app, and not in the framework you've made. That will just need the headers.